# How does this FromDigit module work?

Tags: list-manipulation, number-representation

I am entering the following input:

```
FromDigits[{{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}}, 2]

(* {15/256, 15/256, 15/128, 15/128, 15/256, 15/256, 15/128, 15/128} *)
```

Can anyone please explain the output?

Comment: This is being interpreted as `FromDigits[{{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, #}, 2] & /@ {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}`. Now, look at the second bullet under the "Details" section of the `FromDigits[]` doc page.

Comment: @J.M. - interesting; however, `FromDigits` does not have the attribute `Listable` so that behavior is "unexpected".